# How Do You Use SharePoint Online List Title and Description in form Header json?

Tags: json, forms, sharepoint-online

I would like to use the SharePoint Online **List** Title and **List** Description in form Header json custom formatting. So far I have had no luck discovering how to do this, just how to use columns like "Title" but not the parameter to use for the List title itself. We also use Descriptions heavily and are hoping we can use this to make the transition to SP Online easier for our users.

Have attempted to discover the proper parameter names/formatting for SPO list title and description but no luck yet.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to display the list title and description on the form header using JSON, right? Apologize in advance if I misunderstood.

Comment: yes, that is the question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting currently.

You can only show the values of "columns" on list form header using JSON formatting.

Currently SharePoint JSON formatting does not provide the information related to SharePoint list, like list Title and list Description (which you can change from list settings page).